# How to calculate the possibilty of an event over time

Tags: probability, statistics

Learned statistics before, but totally forgot.

Here is the engineering problem, samples will be taken like 100 times every second, the sample value means what the target is happening (event).

How can I calculate the graph of each event (sample)'s possibility graph over time, so I can analyse when some events happens more by comparing these graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach is to take a number of readings, say 1000 depending upon the frequency, and count events.  You can then plot the number of events per 1000 readings over time to see when they are more or less common.